# IOS:Objective-C: How to combine elements of arrays

Tags: ios, arrays

I have an array of people objects stored in Core Data and I would like to create a string made by combining two attributes of each, as in firstname and lastname.

```
NSArray *firstArr = [[Employees valueForKey:@"first"] allObjects]; 
NSArray *secondArr = [[Employees valueForKey:@"last"] allObjects];
```

I can create a string from one attribute such as "John,Jane" with

```
NSString *firststr = [firstarr componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Can anyone suggest how to make a string that has the first and last names separated by commas as in `John Doe, Jane Doe`?  Imagine there is a method but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
NSArray *firstArr = @[@"Rajat" , @"Rajat1", @"Raj"];
NSArray *secondArr = @[@"Test" , @"Test1", @"Test2"];
NSString * str = @"";
for (int i=0; i< (firstArr<secondArr ? firstArr.count:secondArr.count); i++) {
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,",firstArr[i],secondArr[i]]];
}
str = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-1];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you Rajat.